# How to trigger lambda function Event type: ObjectCreatedByPut

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have CF template below

I need to trigger the lambda function for s3 PUT event

`Event type: ObjectCreatedByPut`

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-s3-notification-config/

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform:  'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'

rData:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            CodeUri: functions/load_data
            FunctionName: sample-function
            Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
            Runtime: python3.8
            MemorySize: 3008
            Timeout: 100
            Role: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/main_service_role
            Environment:
                Variables:
                    bucket_name: sample-bucket
                    file_name: config/test.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-eventsource.html) to your template. But for [S3 event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-s3.html):

> S3 bucket name. This bucket **must** exist in the same template.

Thus your template could be modified as follows:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform:  'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Resources:

  MyBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: test-bucket-3422344

  rData:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: functions/load_data     
      FunctionName: sample-function
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      MemorySize: 3008
      Timeout: 100
      Role: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/main_service_role
      Environment:
        Variables:
          bucket_name: sample-bucket
          file_name: config/test.csv
      Events:
        S3Event:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref MyBucket
            Events: s3:ObjectCreated:Put
```

Comment: in `MyBucket` resource do we need to add Bucket name also? for reference

Comment: @sim You can use a specific bucket name, or you can leave it like I did. Bucket name will be auto-generated, if its not explicitly specified.

Comment: one last question if i want to pass the bucket name "test-bucket" how to pass that in the 'MyBucket' resource

Comment: @sim I updated answer. Bucket names must be globally unique, thus `test-bucket` could be already taken by someone else.

Comment: in the bucket there is particular folder is there, "test/sample/" is the directory name I have added Filter:
                    S3Key:
                    Rules:
                    - Name: prefix
                        Value: test/sample/

Comment: I got error , while triigereing for particular folder

Comment: @sim What error? You could make new question specifically to this new issue? You can provide error messages, current setup and more. Its difficult to speculate based only on the comments.

Comment: I have added new quesiton https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66328370/how-to-add-filter-value-for-s3-trigger-event

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform:  'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'

rData:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
            CodeUri: functions/load_data
            FunctionName: sample-function
            Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
            Runtime: python3.8
            MemorySize: 3008
            Timeout: 100
            Role: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/main_service_role
            Environment:
                Variables:
                    bucket_name: sample-bucket
                    file_name: config/test.csvEvents:
            S3Event:
                Type: S3
                Properties:
                Bucket:
                    Ref: ImagesBucket     # This must be the name of an S3 bucket declared in the same template file
                Events: s3:ObjectCreated:Put
                Filter:
                    S3Key:
                    Rules:
                    - Name: prefix      # or "suffix"
                        Value: value      # The value to search for in the S3 object key names
```

[S3 Event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-s3.html)

[Amazon S3 Event Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html#supported-notification-event-types)

Comment: ImagesBucket do we need to add bucket name?

Comment: I think @marcin already covered all of it :)