# How to add filter value for s3 trigger event

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have created a bucket trigger with following temlate

I need to trigger only for the folder test/sample/ which present in test-bucket-3422344

```
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
    Transform:  'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
    Resources:
    
      MyBucket:
        Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
        Properties:
          BucketName: test-bucket-3422344
    
      rData:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
          CodeUri: functions/load_data     
          FunctionName: sample-function
          Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
          Runtime: python3.8
          MemorySize: 3008
          Timeout: 100
          Role: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/main_service_role
          Environment:
            Variables:
              bucket_name: sample-bucket
              file_name: config/test.csv
          Events:
            S3Event:
              Type: S3
              Properties:
                Bucket: !Ref MyBucket
                Events: s3:ObjectCreated:Put
```

I have added the filter like below parallel to Events

```
       Filter:
            S3Key:
               Rules:
                  - Name: prefix
                  - Value: test/sample
```

I got error

````
E0001 Error transforming template: Resource with id [rData] is invalid. property Filter not defined for resource of type AWS::Serverless::Function```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not-needed `-` in your `Rules`. The corrected template is as follows:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform:  'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Resources:

  MyBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: test-bucket-3422344
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration: 
          - BucketKeyEnabled: true
            ServerSideEncryptionByDefault: 
              SSEAlgorithm: aws:kms

  rData:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: functions/load_data          
      FunctionName: sample-function
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      MemorySize: 3008
      Timeout: 100
      Role: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/main_service_role
      Environment:
        Variables:
          bucket_name: sample-bucket
          file_name: config/test.csv
      Events:
        S3Event:
          Type: S3
          Properties:
            Bucket: !Ref MyBucket
            Events: s3:ObjectCreated:Put   
            Filter: 
              S3Key: 
                Rules: 
                  - Name: prefix
                    Value: test/sample
```

Comment: is Filter: 
              S3Key: 
                Rules: 
                  - Name: prefix
                    Value: test/sample is property of function or Bucket

Comment: @sim Its bucket. You can got to S3 console and check the event details. The prefix should be there.

Comment: i got errro bucket logging must be enabled for MyBucket

Comment: also Resources.rMyBucket.Properties.ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration must use aws:kws encryption

Comment: @sim I updated the answer, but if you have future new requests/issues, it would be better to make new questions for them.

Comment: can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67286332/accessdeniedexception-coming-while-cross-account-amazon-standard-sqs-queue